# Custom Post String for Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, submit

I have a form with input sections like first and name last name

```
input type="text" class="int-input-medium" name="First" value=""
```

if person enters first name "John"

How do I create a Post String?

```
    http://XXXXXXXXX.com/api/test.ashx?First=John
```

Do i create a javascript and if so can i get an example or any other code type i should use for this.
I need it to be using a submit button?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with javascript?  This can be done with a basic html form and a `GET` request.

Comment: For a POST request you need to submit a form, which is basic HTML stuff. It is a GET request if you are appending data to the URL. See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp and https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/post_requests for examples.

Comment: Don't need to use javascript, just wanted the easiest and most efficient way

Comment: @gotuskar I actually have no clue how those links are relevant. You are correct in the fact that `GET` requests append to the url. However, you can easily designate a form to use get/post using `method="get"` (default) or `method="post"`. If you use `GET` the data is sent in the URL which the form handles for you...  With that in mind my recommendation would be to use a form.  Designate it as a `GET` request and to not use JavaScript.  Mainly because there isn't a reason to use JavaScript here since it's not needed (from the information given). Ryan Flood gives an example of this below.

Answer (score 4):

First of all POST values are hidden, I think you want a GET form.  If you tell your form to do this in the form header, it will give you exactly what you want.

```
<form action="someDumbAction" method="GET" name="someDumbName">
```

Answer (score 0):

**OR** Do you want something on this line? i.e. making your Url `:)`

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ppQBK/

Hope it help the cuase `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.button').click(function() {

         var goUrl = 'http://mysite.com/'+ $('#foo').val();
         alert(goUrl);
          window.location = goUrl;
          return false;  // Prevent the default button behaviour
         // or use e.preventDefualt(); API
     });

});
```